# Loop to check CONDITION but run COMMAND only one time

Tags: bash, shell

I need to check condition `statt` continually until it meets `Yes` if `No` only open website once and keep checking  condition `statt` without opening webpage again and again.

what will be the correct approach?

```
statt=$(cat /private/tmp/homee/tat) ##This is a example, in real I am running a command here.

while [[ $statt == "No" ]]
do
    statt=$(cat /private/tmp/homee/tat)
    if [[ $statt == "No" ]]; then
        open https://statckoverflow.com//. ##Only want to open webpage once and wait until condition Yes.
    fi
done

echo "Continue Script....."
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `while` loop runs while `$statt == "No"`, you can call `open` after the `while` loop, so you're sure that `$statt != "No"`;

```sh
statt=$(cat /private/tmp/homee/tat)

while [[ $statt == "No" ]]
do
    statt=$(cat /private/tmp/homee/tat)
done

# After while; so $statt is not 'No', call open once
open https://statckoverflow.com//.

echo "Continue Script....."
```

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you wanted :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
first_time=1
while test "$(</private/tmp/homee/tat)" = no; do
    if  test "$first_time" = 1; then
        open https://statckoverflow.com//. ##Only want to open webpage once and wait until condition Yes.
        first_time=0
    fi
    sleep 1
done

echo "Continue Script....."
```

Or if you can move `open` command outside of `while` loop, you can just do

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
open https://statckoverflow.com//. ##Only want to open webpage once and wait until condition Yes.
while test "$(</private/tmp/homee/tat)" = no; do
    sleep 1
done

echo "Continue Script....."
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
#!/bin/dash
opened='0'
statt="$(command ...)"
while [ "$statt" = 'No' ] ; do
    statt="$(command ...)"
    if [ "$statt" = 'Yes' ]; then
         # do something
    elif [ "$opened" -eq 0 ]; then
         opened='1'
         open 'https://stackoverflow/...'
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```